# Display last 12 months on X-Axis on Scatter Chart ChartJS 2.0?

Tags: javascript, java, html, chart.js

I have a Multi-Axis Scatter Chart with always exactly 12 points to represent the last 12 months (I just assigned 1, 2, ... 12 to the x variables)
https://jsfiddle.net/7tyg0Lub/

[See it here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWhtW.jpg)

As of now it is displaying Jan 1970 in all segments of the x-axis, how would I have it display as the last 12 months:

(Since it's November)
Nov 2016, Dec 2016, Jan 2017 ... Oct 2017

Thanks in advance!!

```
                            xAxes: [{
                                position: "bottom",
                                type: 'time',
                                display: true,
                                time: {
                                    displayFormats: {
                                        'millisecond': 'MMM YYYY',
                                        'second': 'MMM YYYY',
                                        'minute': 'MMM YYYY',
                                        'hour': 'MMM YYYY',
                                        'day': 'MMM YYYY',
                                        'week': 'MMM YYYY',
                                        'month': 'MMM YYYY',
                                        'quarter': 'MMM YYYY',
                                        'year': 'MMM YYYY'
                                    }
                                },
                                gridLines: {
                                    zeroLineColor: "rgba(0,0,0,1)"
                                },
                            }],
```

Comment: Can you please make a jsfiddle or something where we can see code and edit it as needed ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7tyg0Lub/

Comment: Your fiddle is not showing any results ?

Comment: I'm having difficulty with my fiddle, but it is similar with this: https://jsfiddle.net/9gerc01h/